# set text box to automatically get the last day of the month

Tags: excel, vba, userform

In my user form I have a start date and an end date.To get the start tate I used a dtpicker to select the date.I what to get the end date and insert it automatically  into a text box.The end date must be the end of the month:

For Example:

```
start date | 01/02/2015
end date   | 28/02/2015
```

or

```
start date | 01/01/2015
end date   | 31/01/2015
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code work for me:

```
Public Function dhLastDayInMonth(Optional dtmDate As Date = 0) As Date
    ' Return the last day in the specified month.
    If dtmDate = 0 Then
        ' Did the caller pass in a date? If not, use
        ' the current date.
        dtmDate = Date
    End If

  dhLastDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), _
     Month(dtmDate) + 1, 0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the AfterUpdate event of the start date TextBox. Something like.

```
Private Sub startDate_AfterUpdate()
    If IsDate(Me.startDate) Then
        Me.endDate = DateSerial(Year(startDate), Month(startDate) + 1, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```